# DTD and CDATA understanding

Tags: xml, dtd, cdata

Please help me to understand the thing:
here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp
we can read that CDATA means not parsed data so why I'm not allowed to put ">" or "&" sign here as it is not parsed data?

I mean the situation:

```
<!ELEMENT xxx (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST xxx attr CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

in xml:

```
<xxx attr="aaa>aaa">parsed data</xxx>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between [CDATA sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect) in XML documents (which is what the linked w3schools article is about) and the [CDATA type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types) in attribute declarations in DTDs. These are two different concepts.

`>` characters are allowed in attribute values. `<` and `&` however, are not allowed unless escaped. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax.